# builtins.TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'

Tags: python

I'm trying to finish up an assignment for class, but I'm just not getting this last piece.

I'm trying to have a function that, when given the wind speed, gives the associated warning message, but the trick is that the wind speed and warning messages and parameters are in 2 previously defined functions. Also, the teacher wanted us to call both functions all in one line.

So first I created the first 2 functions:

```
def storm_category(speed):
    if speed <= 129:
        return (0)
    if speed >= 130 and speed < 164:
        return (1)
    if 165 <= speed and speed < 189:
        return (2)
    if 190 <= speed and speed < 219:
        return (3)
    if 220 <= speed and speed < 259:
        return (4)
    if speed >= 260:
        return (5)

def category_warning(category):
    if category == 0:
        return "Not  a major threat"
    if category == 1:
        return "Very dangerous winds will produce some damage."
    if category == 2:
        return "Extremely dangerous winds will cause extensive damage."
    if category == 3:
        return "Devastating damage will occur."
    if category == 4:
        return "Catastropic damage will occur"
    if category == 5:
        return "Cataclysmic damage will occur."
```

But in the last function I'm required to use information from both:

```
def warning(speed):
    # Requirement: this function should be one line!

    return storm_category(category_warning)
```

With the above code though, every time I try to return a I get an error saying that "builtins.TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'". It says that the errors are on these lines:

```
return storm_category(category_warning)
```

And

```
if speed <= 129:
        return (0)
```

I'm not sure if my syntax is wrong or what. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `storm_category(category_warning)` - what the heck? `storm_category` is supposed to take a speed, not the `category_warning` function, and `category_warning` is supposed to take a category, such as what you'd get out of an appropriate call to `storm_category`.

Comment: looks like the return of `warning` should be `return category_warning(storm_category(speed))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is because you send the name of function and not the function call. must be:

```
def warning(speed):
    return category_warning(storm_category(speed))
```

> note: in your code when the python interpreter process the operation
>   `speed <= 129`, the python interpreter assumes speed is a callable
>   function.